# Where do these emojis come from?

Tags: fonts, emoji

I have installed `noto-emoji` (thanks Google!) but some of them are still the default from Ubuntu.
I have NOT installed Symbola (ancient ttf font)

See screenshot from getemoji.com - the ones marked with red, are the ones I want to remove.

[image]
What font do I need to remove?

Comment: They probably come from the ancient-ttf font package, or at least that's how it was called. I don't know what the new package name is but maybe this comment gave you a hint.

Comment: Like I wrote, symbola (which is ancient-ttf font package) is not installed.
Edit: I added some text to make it more clear :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [Fonts view of the Firefox Developer Tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/UI_Tour#Fonts_view).

In my case it's **DejaVu Sans** from `fonts-dejavu-core` package but I see some differences from your screenshot.

Comment: Thank you so much. It seems I cant remove those, without removing ubuntu-desktop and other things. Guess I'll just have to live with it.

Comment: In theory you can change the default font that is used, but that depends on desktop environment and what settings a particular software uses. And I don't think it's DejaVu in your case, some of my symbol pictures don't match yours.

Comment: Thats probably because the rest is from noto-emoji-font (from google fonts)

Comment: `ubuntu-desktop` is just a metapackage that can be removed. But you'll have to mark some packages as manually installed to prevent their removal if you decide to use `apt-get autoremove` someday.

Comment: Yes! now it works. I had to remove plymouth, but thats life I guess :)

Comment: **The** ’plymouth’ package? I'm not really sure how `fonts-dejavu-core` removal affected `plymouth`, but that sounds more dangerous now. Are you sure you are able to boot? `plymouth-theme-*` are safe to remove though. On `15.10` `cryptsetup` also depends on `plymouth` and the first one is needed to unlock encrypted disks AFAIU.

Comment: It depended on this: plymouth-label + plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo + ubuntu-desktop meta package.